# Why do some cross domain XMLHttpRequest requests NOT return CORS error

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

For some API's the data is easily accessible and does not throw the following CORS error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://external.service/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my.app' is therefore not allowed access.

I am confused as to why it does NOT throw an error.

In Node.js when I wanted to enable CORS on my server I had to do this:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

I assume the following API's have been setup in a similar way,  but I am looking for validation that this is true. I want my understanding to be technically accurate.

If there is another explanation, I would like to know it.

Some examples of API's that don't throw CORS errors are:

https://itunes.apple.com/hk/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json

http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Star%20Wars&r=json

https://api.github.com/users/**name-of-user**

Comment: Did you look at the headers?

Comment: They all issue `access-control-allow-origin` headers - so, what's the question?

Comment: There is none if that is the answer. Like I said in the query, I just wanted validation.

Comment: Guaranteed that if a browser makes a cross origin request that succeeds, CORS headers are being sent by the server ... CORS is not "optional" and can not be "bypassed"

Comment: When you say CORS can not be bypassed I am confused. When the "access-control-allow-origin" headers are sent and the data is made available what would that be called?  CORS is a standard that can't be bypassed, but by setting the headers the data is accessible and the error  is bypassed - correct ?

Comment: When the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is sent & the browser checks that & find is allows the response to be exposed to the client-side code running at the origin the request was sent from, then that’s just called “working as expected”. That’s not bypassing the CORS standard—instead it’s *following* the CORS standard, which requires browsers to either A) expose the response if it receives an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header saying your origin should be able to see the response or B) not expose it if no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is received or if it doesn’t allow your origin

Comment: To answer your original question, yes, your understanding about those other sites is technically correct. As you assumed, the reason you can access them through XHR or Fetch or whatever from your JavaScript client code running in a browser is that the servers providing them are all configured in a way similar to how you describe you have your own Node server configured. The CORS protocol is just about having the server send those `Access-Control-*` headers. There’s no magic other than that—all those sites handle it the same way you do, just be configuring the server to send the right headers

Answer (score 0):

**Yes your understanding is technically accurate.** You can see the headers from the response of the API examples you mentioned (or anything else that support CORS) and they all have the headers included just like you did in your Node.js app.

Now they may be not doing it in Node.js but adding headers to response is basic stuff for all possible web frameworks or just a matter of setting some configs in the web server itself.

Here's a [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) screenshot that reveals the headers from the github api response.

[image: Headers from Github API]